# Always goto IIS Windows web page when debugging ASP.NET using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

My project is a simple ASP.net web application. It is created from Visual build-in template. When I try to open ASP.NET configuration or default.aspx, IE always goes to IIS Windows page. I have tried this operation using VS2010 and VS2012. The same issue occurred under both IDEs. I have checked "Use Visual Studio Development server" is checked and debug switch is open in web.config file.

Comment: There's your problem right there: IIS *isn't* the VS Development Server.

Comment: I do not mean IIS is VS Development Server. The issue lies in that IIS Windows web page is opened even if I have set the web server to VS Development Server(Cassini).

Comment: What is the URL in your browser address bar? If it is http://localhost of course IIS start page is showed. You need to go to project settings and configure the Start Action and Servers so the correct URL is used by VS.

Comment: I have tried input "http://localhost:33273/asp.netwebadminfiles" manually in IE. IE still goes to IIS Windows web page.

Comment: After several tries, I have found the issue is browser-related. On my own development machine(Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64bit, Internet Explorer 11),  the issue occurs in IE only, but not in Chrome. With some comparison, it seems IE will redirect `<a class="level1 static" href="Default.aspx" tabindex="-1">Home</a>` inside a '<ul role="menuitem"><li></li> ... </ul>' to start page of default web site of IIS namely IIS Windows web page, Chrome will goto expected home page of current web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries, I have found the issue is browser-related. On my own development machine(Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64bit, Internet Explorer 11), the issue occurs in IE only, but not in Chrome. With some comparison, it seems IE will redirect `<a class="level1 static" href="Default.aspx" tabindex="-1">Home</a>` inside a `<ul role="menuitem"><li></li> ... </ul>` to start page of default web site of IIS namely IIS Windows web page, Chrome will goto expected home page of current web site.

Answer (score 0):

try to install iis Express Version or uncheck Your mentioned option to use Cassini

Comment: I want to know the root cause of this issue. As for using IIS Express or IIS web server, it is another topic.